# Android AnyChart library Anychartview.setBackgroundColor() not working

Tags: android, linechart, anychart

AnychartView.setBackgroundColor("#000000")
transparent color not working in android .

Following is my code snippet

```
Cartesian cartesian = AnyChart.line();
mBinding.lineChartMeetingTrend.setChart(cartesian);
mBinding.lineChartMeetingTrend.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
```

Comment: can you post some more code and explain?

Comment: Cartesian cartesian = AnyChart.line();
anychartview.setChart(cartesian);
anychartview.setBackgroundColor("#0fddcf");

please tell me which part you don't understand ?

Comment: how and where are you setting the background as transparent?

Comment: actually I have tried every color code but it does not work, please help. There is method provided in the library i.e. setBackgroundColor() , but it seems it doesnot make any effect

Comment: you can try using `setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: setBackgroundResource() doesnot work